# Doing a JSON request from my phant server to build datafile

Tags: python, json, string

I understand how to get the json string from the phant server I'm running but I need to build a text file with the following format: label=value with each on a separate line.  I've been searching all over to find a way to do this.  Need some help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json,requests
url = "http://192.168.250.55:8080/output/8Bl0DlDexPCpE21gZNads3ZJLpAx/latest.json"
data = json.loads(requests.get(urlsoc).text)
print data

Here is the output from this:

[{u'tempc': u'17.1500', u'altm': u'62.5088', u'tempf': u'62.8700', u'timestamp': u'2017-01-07T17:43:20.870Z', u'windspeedmph': u'0.0000', u'altf': u'205.0813', u'rainin': u'0.0000', u'wifion': u'0', u'humidity': u'27.0000', u'winddir': u'180', u'rainmm': u'0.0000', u'windspeedkmph': u'0.0000', u'voltage': u'3.9787', u'kilopascals': u'100.6010', u'dewptf': u'28.4106', u'soc': u'74.0547', u'dailyrainin': u'0.2750', u'dewptc': u'-1.9941'}]
```

So how can I convert this information into linefeed delimited pairs and write to a file so it looks like this:

tempc=17.1500

altm=62.5088
etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the `items` in each element of the `data` array (the key, value pairs) and then output them using string formatting.

```
import json, requests
url = 'https://data.sparkfun.com/output/9JKlQbq6YMIAVN2Yg6v6/latest.json'
data = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)
with open('outfile', 'w') as f:
    for item in data:
        for key, value in item.items():
            f.write('%s=%s' % (key, value,))
            f.write('\n')
```

If you have unicode data coming back from that endpoint, you can use `codecs.open` instead of `open`.

---

To handle timestamp field parsing/etc.  I typically recommend `dateutil`

```
pip install dateutil
```

Now in your code:

```
from dateutil import parser

. . .
with open('outfile', 'w') as f:
    for item in data:
        dt_timestamp = item.get('timestamp')
        if dt_timestamp:
            dt_timestamp = parser.parse(dt_timestamp)
            # convert the python `datetime` however you would like
            item['timestamp'] = dt_timestamp
        for key, value in item.items():
            f.write('%s=%s' % (key, value,))
            f.write('\n')
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, I'm quite the noob, but running this code produces an error that complains that key is not defined.  Do I run this code for each data pair and change the value of key accordingly?

Comment: @RobertMantel:  There was a typo in my code above.  I have updated it so that it should work better.

Comment: Thanks for the update...seems to still throw this error:  AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'item' .  Couple things you can change to my code to test it as I have this private phant server but also a public stream here: https://data.sparkfun.com/output/9JKlQbq6YMIAVN2Yg6v6/latest.json  also the urlsoc in the get should just be url.

Comment: I just tried this code against the provided endpoint and it worked fine.  I think you misspelled `items` as `item`.  As for the `urlsoc`/`url` That was copied from your original post.

Comment: that url is an https

Comment: yep, my bad it's working for me too.  Many thanks sir!

Comment: I'm wondering if I can bug you for one more thing.  One of the key-value pairs is a timestamp in ISO 8601 format that I want to convert to epoch format.  Is there some way within this script to do the conversion and then write the file with the same 'key=value'/n format in the file?  Would it just be adding an additional for loop nested between the two existing ones to cherry pick the "timestamp" key?

Comment: Much appreciated, that was incredibly fast.  So I need that full line "from dateutil import parser" to handle the date conversion along with installing the function using pip?

Comment: Yes, that is what will let you convert datetime strings into python datetime objects.